# PayPal ExpressCheckout (Payflow): Invalid vendor accountError Code: 26

Tags: php, api, paypal

This is driving me crazy! I can't get the PayPal express (Payflow?) api to work....

**paypal sandbox tells me:**

Test Account:   AAAA.B_CCCCCCCCCC_biz@XXXXX.com

API Username:   AAAA.B_CCCCCCCCCC_biz_api1.XXXXX.com

API Password:   DDDDDDDDDD

Signature:  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

**in the paypayfunctions.php i wrote:**

$API_User="AAAA.B_CCCCCCCCCC_biz@XXXXX.com";

$API_Password="DDDDDDDDDD";

$API_Vendor="AAAA.B_CCCCCCCCCC_biz@XXXXX.com";

$API_Partner="PayPal";

...

And when I test the service, all i get is "**SetExpressCheckoutDetails API call failed. Error Message: Invalid vendor accountError Code: 26**"

The PayPal documentation and examples are terribly complex, all I want to do is having a simple button that links to paypal to start the payment of XXX euro's to account YYYY....

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to agree, the PayPal documentation is a mess. Bits of information are scattered across several PayPal sites, parts of the documentation are inaccurate and some [basic things are nowhere to be found](https://www.x.com/people/PP_MTS_Chad/blog/2010/06/22/checking-for-the-most-recent-version).

Comment: Your PayPal account should be a PRO account before you can use the Express Checkout with Payflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express Checkout and Payflow are two separate PayPal services. Your sandbox credentials (which include a signature) are for Express Checkout. The script asks for a partner, which is specific to Payflow.

1. What do you want to use? Express Checkout or Payflow? See the paragraphs below for more information on the two.
2. Are you sure the script is for Express Checkout?
3. Is the script connecting to the sandbox or live API? The Express Checkout sandbox API is located at https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp.

**Express Checkout** is primarily used for payments using a PayPal account. You can set up a sandbox environment at [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com/). Within the sandbox you can create test accounts, at [sandbox.paypal.com](http://sandbox.paypal.com/). See the [PayPal API Reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference) for more details.

**Payflow** is a payment gateway that allows you to pay using a credit card or checks, among others. PayPal accounts are not supported by Payflow. You can [sign up for an account](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-get-started-outside), which can be used for testing *and* real payments after you upgrade the account. See the User's [Guide for Payflow Link (PDF)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowLink_Guide.pdf) for more details.

Comment: It seemed I mixed up Payflow with PayPal! I created a paypal sandbox account, but I used a Payflow api...

I corrected this already and now I get to the part where I can actually make the (sandbox) payment.

I noticed that page doesn't display the amount to be payed....any idea why that is?

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Dirk: Not from the top of my head, and I don't have any time to look into it right now, sorry. Glad to see you got it working though :)

Comment: Years later and this is still causing confusion. The person responsible for naming the various Paypal payment methods should be flogged.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**
PayPal returned result code 26 - Invalid vendor account when processing a transaction.

**Cause**
You may get result code 26 if:

- **You just activated your account.**

A vendor account doesn't become active until at least an hour after it was created. Typically, a database update begins at 20 minutes past the hour and lasts about 20 minutes. If your account becomes active while the database is updating (after the 20-minute mark), you must wait until after the next hour's update before you can use it.

- **The login information is incorrect.**

Verify the information you entered in the User, Vendor, Partner, and Password fields.
Check that you sent the correct Partner value.
The primary user's Merchant ID should be in the User field. For a secondary Payflow Pro user, the User field should contain the password assigned by the primary user.
All fields are case-sensitive.
**

- **The bank BIN number is unknown.**

** For PayPal Australia (VSA) only, result code 26 indicates that the customer's credit card is issued by a credit union or small financial institution. The processor, FDRA, has no bank identification number (BIN) on file for the card, which triggers the error message,"No Universal Account - Response code 42." You must get another credit card or form of payment from your customer.

**Solution**
Check that all values in use are both correct values and proper case (all values are case-sensitive).